# Magento 2 items orders and invoice not show in customer account orders list

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, sales-order, shipping-methods

Hello Guys Please help me

**Magento ver. 2.3.0**

Date **2/20/20** place orders display only, not display **2019** orders in live site

I checked it is working right on local server

I run all these commands but nothing happened

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

> [2020-03-05 08:17:09] main.CRITICAL: Warning: Illegal string offset
>   'info_buyRequest' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/xyz.com/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Item.php
>   on line 481 [] []

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the table **sales_order_item**, you should save the column **product_options** as **JSON** and in that, there must have one **key  = info_buyRequest**

Comment: Thankyou so much

Comment: @DineshThakur you need to check whether there are emails in the table 'sales_order_grid'

Comment: Hi, any idea for this:: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307038/error-running-the-setupdicompile-command-magento-2-3-0