# Error running the `setup:di:compile` command Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, command-line, setup-di-compile

Run::

**/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php -dmemory_limit=3G bin/magento setup:di:compile**

Error screenshot::

[image]

**Any one can help me**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check again what the version PHP is

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply > my PHP ver: https://prnt.sc/rh10w7

Comment: You need to open and check carefully the "file vendoer/magento/module-eav/Model/Form/Fieldset.php". Maybe there are some syntax errors or ''}'' is missing at the end of the file

Comment: Thanks for reply @litExtension Magento Migration > one more que. any idea > https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/307413/magento-2-custom-attribute-and-show-product-if-attribute-yes

Comment: Yes is syntax error but after solve error is facing new error > https://prnt.sc/riummh

Comment: Check status for module my temando_shipping module is disable

Answer (score 1):

Try to run /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php -dmemory_limit=3G bin/magento setup:upgrade and then run the di:compile

/opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php -dmemory_limit=3G bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv - It helps you to see the exactly file where you are getting error

Comment: i am  running command after php -dmemory_limit=3G bin/magento setup:upgrade > facing error [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTS0m.png ]

Comment: Did you try compile with -vvv? it will show from where the error starts. Make sure the vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Form/Fieldset.php doesn't have any issue at EOD